# Piping nginx -V to grep doesn't color matches

Tags: bash, grep, xterm, xfce

nginx/1.17.3, GNU grep 2.27 and xterm-256color capable terminal (Xfce terminal) for some reason doesn't provide colored matches in its output.
I've tried this:

1. nginx -V | grep brotli -o --color=always -C9999
2. nginx -V | grep -o --color=always -C9999 brotli
3. nginx -V | grep --color=always -C9999 brotli
4. nginx -V | grep brotli --color=always -C9999
5. nginx -V | grep brotli -o --color=always
6. nginx -V | grep -o --color=always brotli
7. nginx -V | grep --color=always brotli
8. nginx -V | grep brotli --color=always

But it simply doesn't highlight text, only meaningless wall of white text that is nginx compile options. $PS1 is colored, so terminal isn't inherently broken!

Comment: I believe you shouldn't be using profanities on this forum, even in a shortened form. Even the word "hell" would be nicer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to redirect `stderr`

```
nginx -V 2>&1 | grep --color=always -e 'http'
```

Learn more about `2>&1` here: [In the shell, what does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean)